# If request does not exist in cache, fetch from server and add to cache

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, service-worker

I just started working with service workers, and I don't fully understand the way they work yet. I have a problem with my code.

What I want to achieve is having all files stored in cache on first load. This bit works fine, and I use a list of all the files I know of that it will cache.

I would like to add a feature where my service worker will cache files is hasn't seen before when they are first loaded *(aka files that are not in the list I made)*

I wrote a piece of the code, but although it seems to add files to the cache, it doesn't seem to work reliably, and when I view my cache usage in Chrome, it also seems to cache some files that the `on-install` script has already cached.

What is the best way to write this piece of code to accomplish my goals?

thanks

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          console.log("new file encountered - adding to cache: ");
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```